# setFocusTraversable for a Node with children in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, focus, openjfx

#### (My) expected behaviour:

When you call [`setFocusTraversable(false)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#setFocusTraversable(boolean)) on a Node with children (i.e. the Node has a method `getChildren()` that returns a List of `Node`s) the `focusTraversable` properties of that node and all its children get the value `false`.

#### Actual behaviour:

However, when I call `setFocusTraversable(false)` on for example a [`TextFlow`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/text/TextFlow.html), its children are still being able to receive focus. This is illustrated in the code below.

Why does the `setFocusTraversable(boolean)` method work this way, and how should one work around this limitation?

```java
// File: App.java
package nl.aronhoogeveen.bugreports;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Hyperlink;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.text.TextFlow;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


/**
 * JavaFX App
 */
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        // TextFlow 1
        Text text1 = new Text("This is text1");
        Hyperlink hyperlink1 = new Hyperlink("This is hyperlink1");
        Text text2 = new Text("This is text2");
        Hyperlink hyperlink2 = new Hyperlink("This is hyperlink2");

        TextFlow textFlow1 = new TextFlow(text1, hyperlink1, text2, hyperlink2);
        textFlow1.setFocusTraversable(false);

        // TextFlow 2 (CustomTextFlow)
        Text text3 = new Text("This is text3");
        Hyperlink hyperlink3 = new Hyperlink("This is hyperlink3");
        Text text4 = new Text("This is text4");
        Hyperlink hyperlink4 = new Hyperlink("This is SPARTAAAAA");

        CustomTextFlow textFlow2 = new CustomTextFlow(text3, hyperlink3, text4, hyperlink4);
        textFlow2.customSetFocusTraversable(false);

        BorderPane rootBorderPane = new BorderPane();
        rootBorderPane.setTop(textFlow1);
        rootBorderPane.setBottom(textFlow2);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(rootBorderPane));
        stage.sizeToScene();
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

```java
// File: CustomTextFlow.java
package nl.aronhoogeveen.bugreports;

import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.text.TextFlow;

public class CustomTextFlow extends TextFlow {
    public CustomTextFlow(Node... children) {
        super(children);
    }

    /**
     * Sets the property focusTraversable of all children's children to {@code b}.
     *
     * @param b the value to set for the properties
     */
    public void customSetFocusTraversable(boolean b) {
        for (Node child : getChildren()) {
            // Assume for simplicity that the children are not Parents or other types that have children
            child.setFocusTraversable(b);
        }
    }
}
```

I filed a [bug](https://github.com/controlsfx/controlsfx/issues/1321) on the ControlsFX component `HyperlinkLabel` regarding this behaviour, and after investigating I discovered that this behaviour was already present in the JavaFX `TextFlow` component that is used by the HyperlinkLabel and therefore I am posting this question.

Comment: hmm .. what makes you think it's  a property that's applied to the complete subtree of a parent?

Comment: just checked the doc - nothing to support your expectation, which means the expectation is wrong in the general case. If needed, it's up to implementors of a control to disable focustraversal into children, f.i. by using a custom focusTraversalPolicy or binding their property to parent's (as you basically do - except missing any change)

Comment: It is very neat to bind the `focusTraversableProperty` of the children to the parent. I did not think of that. Your comment perfectly answered both my questions then. Thanks for thinking along. If you make your comment into an answer I will except it

Comment: You could also, if you don't care whether your children receive events, just use `disableProperty` for parent set that to false.